# Filter those rows that have most rows in in a related table, while also doing a distinct query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a Media model that has a many-to-many relationship to Artist (one Media can have many artists and one Artist can belong to many media).

```
class Media(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        "media_id", primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name="media_set")

class Artist(models.Model):
      """Artist model."""

      id = models.UUIDField(
          "artist_id", primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
      )
      name = models.CharField("artist_name", max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Also each user can rate each Media through a relational table named UserMedia, one Media can have multiple UserMedia.

```
class UserMedia(models.Model):
    """User Media model."""

    id = models.UUIDField(
        "user_media_id", primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

I want to do a query where I order by most ratings (UserMedia), while also filter the queryset for distinct Artist, such that each artist appears only once in the queryset and that Media is returned with the most UserMedia related rows (or counts).

I can do the two things separately, order by most counts or do a distinct artists filter.

Here's the query that I have right now:

```
user = request.user
distinct_artists = models.Media.objects.distinct("artists__id")
queryset = (
    models.Media.objects.annotate(
        count_ratings=Count("usermedia"),
    ).filter(
        count_ratings__gte=1
    )
    .order_by("onboarding_view", "-count_ratings")
    .filter(
        id__in=distinct_artists
    )
```

The resultset returns distinct Artist, but not the Media with the most counts of UserMedia for this artist.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated the post with the models and updated the query